# VBA code that replace VLOOKUP without limit of characters

Tags: excel, vba

Today I have an issue with the VLOOKUP formula because of the long text I'm looking for, I also tried FIND and MATCH formulas, but it doesn't work, so now I'm looking for a solution in VBA.
There is a code I find here on Stack Overflow :

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell, A As Range, B As Range)
        For Each cell In A
            If cell.Value = searchCell.Value Then
                    betterSearch = B.Cells(cell.Row, 1)
                    Exit For
            End If
            betterSearch = "Not found"
        Next

End Function
```

So in the formula area, I write this : “**=betterSearch(A14;Sheets2!A3:E60;D3:D60)**”

But it every time write the value of the 2nd row under…

Notice : **I'm French, that's why I write “;” and not “,”**

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but I note that `B.Cells(cell.Row, 1)` is a relative range.

Comment: try `betterSearch = cell.EntireRow.Cells(B.Column)` this way you are extending from the matched cell into the return value column, this should force the row # to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to write :

```
        For Each cell In A
            If cell.Value = searchCell.Value Then
                    betterSearch = cell.EntireRow.Cells(B.Column)
                    Exit For
            End If
            betterSearch = "Not found"
        Next

End Function
```